# How to use a js class in a dart file

Tags: javascript, dart

I have a class in Dart like this

```
import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js' as js;

class VistorianTab {
   void showMatrix() {
      var dataset = new networkcube.DataSet({
          name: dataSetName,
          nodeTable: [...],
          linkTable: [...],
          nodeSchema: {...},
          linkSchema: {...} 
    });
```

}

I get the error because networkcube isn't defined, I imported the library in the index.html.
The library is this : https://github.com/networkcube/vistorian/blob/master/core/networkcube.js
I'm new to Dart, I'm sorry if I repeteaded a question.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: See the documentation here: https://pub.dev/packages/js

You'll need to add the proper @JS() annotations. e.g.

@JS('network') external Object network;

Comment: I receive this error 
Fields can't be declared to be 'external'.
Try removing the keyword 'external', or replacing the field by an external getter and/or setter.